# ¿Como utilizo el FileReader de JS para previsualizar varias imagenes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, archivo

Actualmente quisiera seleccionar multiples imagenes y previsualizarlas en 4 elementos de tipo img que ya tengo predefinidos, pero lo que pasa es que solo se previsualiza la ultima que selecciono en la ultima posicion y el resto no se mueve ni se cambiar, despues debuguee en el navegador y ahi si que funciono pero en release no me hace lo mismo y solo me detecta la ultima iteracion de mi ciclo.

Codigo JS:

```
$("#GaleriaPrincipal").change(function(e) {

for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {
        var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var resultado;
                reader.onload = function() {
            resultado=reader.result;
                $("#PrincipalImg"+i).attr("src",resultado); 
                console.log($("#PrincipalImg"+i));  
        }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);

      }

});
```

Resultado final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se da porque el evento `reader.onload` es asíncrono y el `for` se termina de ejecutar antes de que dicho evento suceda, dejando a `i` en su valor máximo.

Luego cuando comienzan a suceder los eventos `reader.onload`, `i` ya fue establecida a su máximo valor, por lo que todos leen la variable `i` con el mismo valor.

**Demo usando setTimeout para simular el evento asíncrono**

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Evento! i = ', i);
  });
  console.log('Bucle for i = ', i);
}
```

---

### Solución 1:

Como señala @gugadev, simplemente utilizar [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let) en lugar de [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

> `let` te permite declarar variables limitando su alcance (`scope`) al bloque, declaración, o expresión donde se está usando. Lo anterior diferencia  `let` de la palabra reservada `var`, la cual define una variable global o local en una función sin importar el ámbito del bloque.

#### Ejemplo:

```
$("#GaleriaPrincipal").change(function(e) {

  // AQUI usamos let para definir a i
  for (let i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {
    var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var resultado;
    reader.onload = function() {
      resultado = reader.result;
      $("#PrincipalImg" + i).attr("src", resultado);
      console.log($("#PrincipalImg" + i));
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
});
```

---

### Solución 2:

Podrías utilizar `function.bind` para pasar un contexto (*objeto con el valor de `i`*) a la función que pasas a `reader.onload`

#### Ejemplo:

```
$("#GaleriaPrincipal").change(function(e) {

  for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {
    var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var resultado;
    reader.onload = function() {
      resultado = reader.result;

      // AQUI usamo el contexto para obtener el valor de i
      $("#PrincipalImg" + this.i).attr("src", resultado);

      console.log($("#PrincipalImg" + this.i));
    }.bind({i: i}); // <-- AQUI usamos bind

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
});
```

#### Referencias:

- [function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: ¿O simplemente usar `let` en lugar de `var`?

Comment: @gugadev, he actualizado mi respuesta. No puedo creer que se me pasara por alto...

Answer (score 0):

En este caso estaríamos hablando de que te hace falta controlar lo que recibes en tu FileReader que es un array ya que despues de todo lo tienes que recibir forzosamente en un input de entrada de archivos (files) por lo que al pasarlo por el FileReader necesitarias pasar un metodo que tiene dicha libreria que seria el metodo `readAsDataURL` y se veria de la siguiente forma.

```
// Creamos el objeto de la clase FileReader
let etiqueta = document.getelementById('img.input');
let reader = new FileReader();

// Leemos el archivo subido y se lo pasamos a nuestro fileReader
reader.readAsDataURL(etiqueta.files[0]);
```

Como puedes ver pasar primero en ese caso el parametro 0 pero para el resto de tus imagenes tendrias que pasar el parametro correspontiente, de acuerdo a lo que veo en tu JQuery tendria que quedar de la siguiente manera si es que no me equivoco.

```
for (i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {
       var reader = new FileReader();
       var resultado;

       reader.onload = function(event) {
           resultado=reader.result;
           $("#PrincipalImg"+i).attr("src",resultado); 
           console.log($("#PrincipalImg"+i));    
       }

       reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
}
```

> No se si se implemente exactamente de esta forma porque aun desconozco de JQuery pero creo que debería de funcionar.